# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when sending an asynchronous using NSURLConnection

Tags: swift

This function has a strange issue:

```
func retrieveToken() {
        var postRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com"));
        postRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        var responseData = NSMutableData();
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(postRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            responseData = NSMutableData(data:data);
            })
        var responseDict:Dictionary<String,AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: nil) as Dictionary;
    }
```

This function is supposed to send a POST request to the URL (which is valid) to receive a token. However, for some reason when I run this code I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION at the line where I set the postRequest's HTTPMethod to POST. I feel like I'm overlooking something really obvious but I can't see what. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overlooking (at least) two major points.

1. The data you are passed in your completion handler is an Optional, so you need to be prepared for it to be nil.
2. Your NSJSONSerialization is performed immediately after calling sendAsynchronousReguest, and the completion handler will not have been called at that point.

It's most likely that the first of these issues could lead to the crash you're experiencing, because you at some point try to dereference `data` but it happens to be nil.  But it might be that NSJSONSerialization doesn't like being passed an empty `NSMutableData` instance.

Read up on Optionals, then read up on asynchronous programming, and then take a look again at what you're trying to achieve.  Just going with a Synchronous network request is going to lead to a lousy user experience as the interface freezes waiting for your network request to complete.

Comment: You're right, when I pass empty data to NSJSONSerialization, it crashes. The sendSynchronousRequest solution really is only so I can focus on other parts of the program for now, but I won't be sticking to it in the final result.

Comment: That's most likely because you're trying to force downcast it to a non-optional Dictionary and it wants to return nil.  Probably you should make responseDict optional: `var responseDict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? = ... as? Dictionary`

Comment: Note that this currently breaks Playground, I think it's something to do with Quicklook but haven't dug too deep.  Optionals definitely what you need though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using sendSynchronousRequest instead:

```
responseData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(postRequest, returningResponse: nil, error: nil) as NSData;
```